# CHM refuses to open from some folders

Tags: windows, chm

Hopefully you have a Windows OS on which you can open **[.chm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help)** files correctly.

Let's say you have a file called `A.chm` that opens correctly

- Now create a folder called `f.column`
- Copy `A.chm` to `f.column`   folder

Now double-click to open the `A.chm` file in Explorer and you will see a dialog with the message:

> Cannot open the file: `D:\f.column\API_GB.chm`.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens?

This is a developer-related problem, because typically the user will be launching help from an application's help menu, and are likely to believe that the bug is in the application and contact the developer.  This is particularly likely to happen in applications that install into the user's profile, because the bug will be triggered if the username happens to contain `.col`.

Comment: This is weird - I can reproduce. It seems like any folder named like `*.col*` triggers the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [known problem](http://microsoft.public.helpauthoring.narkive.com/aWYky6TN/cannot-open-chm-file-if-in-a-folder-called-a-col), and it [cannot be fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/neerajag/archive/2006/04/26/584144.aspx).

When Microsoft delivered its MSDN Library in the old HTML Help 1.x format, they used `.col` files to list all the `.chm` files that were to be included in the **col**lection.

The only solution is to **move the CHM to another folder.**

> Any chm file that is in a folder named `*.col*` will not open. Example paths that will cause this error:
>
> `C:\asdf.col\TFSInstall.chm`
>
> `C:\Documents and Settings\john.coltrane\Desktop\TFSInstall.chm`

Comment: Or you can symlink to this file/folder, which also avoids issues with network drives.

Comment: Just reeks of bad coding. I can understand *.col files or a folder that ends with .col but having .col anywhere in the path... This is just plain crazy